# Python - efficient assigning of same value to list slice

Tags: python, list, performance, slice, assign

If I have Python's list `l` what is the most efficient (fastest, high-speed) way to assign same value `v` to slice `[start : stop : step]` (e.g. for positive `step`) of this list?

For my task I need just a shallow copy (copy reference). Also as extension of my task would be interesting to know efficient ways for deep-copy assigning of same value.

Are next two methods the fastest ways possible? Or there exist other methods that are much faster?

```
l[start : stop : step] = [v] * ((stop - start + step - 1) // step)
```

and:

```
for i in range(start, stop, step):
    l[i] = v
```

timings:

```
python -m timeit -s "l = list(range(10 ** 6)); start, stop, step, v = 10, 100000, 2, 99" "l[start : stop : step] = [v] * ((stop - start + step - 1) // step)" 
200 loops, best of 5: 1.24 msec per loop

python -m timeit -s "l = list(range(10 ** 6)); start, stop, step, v = 10, 100000, 2, 99" "for i in range(start, stop, step): l[i] = v" 
50 loops, best of 5: 5.38 msec per loop
```

So first variant is `4.3x` times faster.

First variant needs unnecessary creation of sometimes large list of same `v` values, also when assigning to list slice python could really re-create whole list `l`! Second solution uses slow pure-Python loop.

But what I really need is some built-in fast (`C`-based) standard Python's function like `l.set_to_range(slice(start, stop, step), v)`, is there anything like this? (at least for `step = 1`). Same as in standard library of `C++` exists [std::fill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) for doing this thing for step=1: `std::fill(vec.begin() + start, vec.begin() + stop, v)`.

Or if no built-in method exists I'm looking for suggestions on what other faster methods (except for those two above) exist.

Comment: "Efficient" by what metric?  If you mean time, then what did you get when you timed the two methods (see `timeit`), and what is still concern for you?

Comment: @Prune Efficient meaning fastest.

Comment: @Prune I didn't measure these two methods because my task is not to compare these two methods but to find out the canonical fastest way of doing this. I put these methods just for example of one way (maybe not fastest) of achieving task. Basically I was looking for built-in method.

Comment: @Prune Maybe you miss-understood what I really wanted. I didn't want to compare these two methods, I can compare them myself by timeit. I want to find out some other new method that is fastest. But if none exist I'll use these two in my code.

Comment: Somebody voted to close the question. What's wrong with it?

Comment: There are two close votes and nobody told what's wrong in this question to be closed.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I've removed my closure vote and reversed the down-vote.  There is no Python built-ion for this, but perhaps someone who is intimate with language internals, can give you a better "skip-fill" technique.